# iperf can't connect from remote machine

Tags: cloud, port, remote-access, bandwidth, iperf

I am trying to measure the network bandwidth between two cloud virtual machines, using iperf. Machine A runs

```
    iperf -s
```

and machine B

```
    iperf -c <ip of machine A>.
```

This doesn't work, while executing

```
    iperf -c localhost
```

in machine A works fine. The firewall is not the problem as I have opened the port needed(5001 , using sudo ufw allow 5001).

Also, I would like to note that the whole process works flawlessly on machines running on another cloud provider.

Answer (score 0):

Just solved the problem. Turns out the security group of the VMs should also have port 5001 open (so somehow I should know that I would need this port opened at the time of the VM creation?). Also, even though I added the corresponding firewall rule, it didn't work until I changed security groups.